# How to change language in android based on web service

Tags: android, web-services, localization, sharedpreferences, realm

Currently, I'm working on the Android project where I'm using `English` as a primary language. I'm using `strings.xml` file for string constants.

Now, I want to change language dynamically based on web service. This service will be created based on user choice(In Settings).

> I know we have to create separate strings.xml file for every language
>   support.

But In my case, the user will create the string constants in the server application for multilingual support. Those strings will be converted into JSON web service. Now, I want to access that service and change the language dynamically.

Also, how to store those strings locally(SharedPreference or Realm DB or anything else)

Comment: You could be using properties as any other java application but you must manage it by yourself and, notice, that in android the lang depends on the system lang and you are creating a usability issue with this

Comment: Then which way to support many languages.

Comment: I know one solution is creating separate strings.xml file. But It won't work in my case